# Array loop not returning expected output in Python

Tags: python, arrays, loops, iterator

```
pressures = [[5,6,7],
             [8,9,10],
             [11,12,13],
             [14,15,16]]
i = 0
while (i == 2):
    for row in pressures[i:]:
        cycle[i] = row[i]
row[1]
```

Please any idea why the above code is returning just the last value of the array which is 15

I expect the output to be ;

```
[ 6,
  9,
 12,
 15]
```

Comment: This code doesn't return anything, and the `while` loop is a no-op since there is no way for `i` to be 2.  You might need to include more of your actual code.

Comment: Please recheck/reformat your code. It does not return anything because the while loop never runs, since `i != 2`.

Comment: When reformatting your code as recommended above, please also make sure the indentation level is correct for each line

Comment: You probably want an if statement inside another for loop instead of the while loop.

Answer (score 3):

If all you want is the middle column returned, then you can do that by iterating through the rows and taking the `1` element:

```py
pressures = [[5,6,7],
             [8,9,10],
             [11,12,13],
             [14,15,16]]


middle_col = []
for row in pressures:
    middle_col.append(row[1])
```

Equivalently, you can do this in one line:

```py
pressures = [[5,6,7],
             [8,9,10],
             [11,12,13],
             [14,15,16]]

middle_col = [row[1] for row in pressures]
```

The best way, though, is probably to use NumPy with array indexing:

```py
import numpy as np

pressures = np.array([[5,6,7],
                      [8,9,10],
                      [11,12,13],
                      [14,15,16]])

middle_col = pressures[:, 1]
```

which will return a numpy array which looks like `np.array([6,9,12,15])`.

Comment: Thank you this solves my problem. But what if I need to loop through I.e to return any column I specify not just one at a time. That will be very helpful. Thanks

Comment: you just loop through the indices of the columns.  instead of `row[1]`, it would be `row[i]` where `i` is your iteration variable.  Likewise for `pressures[:,i]`

Answer (score 0):

`i = 0` and just after   `while (i == 2):` are  not compatible